# In QuickBase, is there a way to make one field have unique user access?

Tags: quickbase

I'm the QuickBase Admin for my QuickBase app. In the app, there's a dashboard report that's used by individuals with viewer access; that way, they can see their students' data, but can't edit the app, tables, structures, etc.

My app's users want to be able to edit one field with notes on that row's data (each row is a student's data, so they'd want to use that field to add notes on that individual), but viewers don't have editing/data entry access tn any column. **Is there a way for users to have editing/data entry access to one field, but not the others?**

I know with Tableau and other BI software, this isn't possible, but I wanted to ask since my users asked.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.
Actually there are more ways to implement this needs.

My opinion better if you create a new table and make a relationship between the student data and a (new) Notes table and you will be able to setup edit rights eg by record owner.

An other way, you can allow the edit right for your users and you can make a restriction on field level. In this case you have to go through on each field and at the Advanced section you will find Permission - Restrict access by role.

Hopefully you do not have a lot of fields :)

Comment: I agree that a child table is typically a better solution. It's easier to manage and in this case allows you to have multiple notes per student record.